# Watermark / Merge text with Image Xamarin forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, renderer

Any way to create a watermark with **ImageSource** and a text? for Xamarin forms for **ios** and **android**? 
Or Is it possible to do it with a custom renderer for both platforms?

I can do 2 images but not image and text

**ios:**

```
image1.Draw (new CoreGraphics.CGRect (
                0, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height));

image2.Draw (new CoreGraphics.CGRect (
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width / 4,
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height / 4,
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width / 2,
UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height / 2));

combinedImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext ();
UIGraphics.EndImageContext ();
```

Example of what I need for android and ios:

[image]

Comment: Did you try with a classic .net library?

Comment: @Daniel wish I could, I'm using PCL (portable .net 4.5 library)

Comment: For android watermark, you could refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45774523/xamrin-android-add-image-watermark/45775848#45775848